# Show live screens of other applications in one application window

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to show in one application window (maximized) live screens of another applications that are running concurrently.

I have the following conceptual idea (see below screenshot): the main application is showing while multiple excel applications are running concurrently. Instead of clicking (or tabbing) between applications or resize these windows to be shown on screen, I would want to simply have the main application maximized to show life screens of all these opened excel workbooks.

[image]

Comment: I like the idea. Somehow it should be possible, the taskbar in W7 has (somewhat) functionality like this.

Comment: For my application, I will need to determine what to do next according to another applications's "behavior" or "looks" that is not quantifiable by data etc and has to be determined visually. It will be a pain to constantly flipping through applications (or tabbing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use periodic calls to `PrintWindow` for that.

I'm not completely happy with this solution for it seems a bit hacky. But it also scans hidden windows.

The code is

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, int nFlags

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct RECT
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}

public static Bitmap GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    RECT rect;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, out rect);

    int width = rect.Right - rect.Left;
    int height = rect.Bottom - rect.Top;
    if (width > 0 && height > 0)
    {
        // Build device context (dc)
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Graphics gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();

        // drawing options
        int nFlags = 0;

        // execute call
        PrintWindow(hWnd, hdcBitmap, nFlags);

        // some clean-up
        gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
        gfxBmp.Dispose();

        return bmp;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }

} // end function getWindow
```